# mediarecorder addEventListener is not working in Chrome/Safari

Tags: vue.js, web-mediarecorder

I am using mediarecorder in a vue.js app. The code snippet is below. The inline function for ondataavailable executes. However, neither of the two options to specify a function handler for onstop get invoked.

Is there a workaround to this issue?

```
      const options = { mimeType: "audio/webm" };
      mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
        console.log("in dataAvailable", e.data.size);
        if (e.data.size > 0) recordedChunks.push(e.data);
      };

      mediaRecorder.onstop = this.stopRecordingEvent;
      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", this.stopRecordingEvent);
```

Using an inline function for the stop event like dataavailable works, however that gives error in the highlighted line:

```
      mediaRecorder.onstop = function () {
        console.log("recording stopped event");

        // save the recording bytes in an array

        const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks);
        const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var recording = {
          blob: blob,
          url: audioURL,
          id: arrRecordings.length + 1,
        };
        console.log(recording.id, recording.url);

        //this line gives an error
        this.recordings.push(recording);
        console.log(arrRecordings);

        recordedChunks.length = 0;
      };
```

Comment: What is `stopRecordingEvent` exactly, how is it defined. If your inline version does throw it's because there, `this` is the MediaRecorder instance, you'd want to make it an arrow function: `mediaRecorder.onstop = (evt) => { ...`

Comment: i think you don't know how `this` keyword works or how to use them.  both `this.stopRecordingEvent` & `this.recordings` doesn't exists (both are `undefined`).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had to switch to the arrow functions to get the code to work. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

event ondataavailable works after mediaRecorder stop() function

Comment: Nope, it's dataavailable first, then stop.

Comment: https://github.com/helmutkemper/iotmaker.webassembly/blob/e050249e14f38045a85faa57651e8a7339adc749/browser/html/typeTagVideo.go#L4645

I'm converting golang to webassembly and only managed to get it to work like this, when recording stops.

Comment: You can follow my code and suggest something better.

Comment: Ah so you meant they have to call `mediaRecorder.stop()` for the *dataavailable* event fires? That's not necessarily true either, if you let the recorder record long enough the dataavailable event will fire eventually, and if you need it to fire at regular intervals you may want to pass a *timeslice*  argument to `mediaRecorder.start(timeSlice)`. And sorry but no, I can't read your code to find out what **you** did wrong.

Comment: thanks, i corrected my code